# Merging line geometries in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm having a problem merging multiple lines into one geometry. Line geometry was built using the CubicBezierCurve3:

```
const curve = new CubicBezierCurve3(
            point1,
            point2,
            point3,
            point4
        );
        const geometry = new BufferGeometry();
        const points = curve.getPoints(16);
        geometry.setFromPoints(points);
```

Then these two geometries were merged using BufferGeometryUtils:

```
const line = new Line(BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries([line1Geometry, line2Geometry], false), new LineBasicMaterial())
```

As a result, the desired figure turned out, but an extra line came from somewhere that connects them.

[line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJy0h.png)

If I change the order when merging, then I get a different line. I don't understand how to solve this problem.

[line2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/137Zn.png)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `THREE.Line` for this use case since it represents a continuous line. So if you merge two separate lines into one, there will be no gap that separates both.

You have to use `THREE.LineSegments` however that means you have to pre-process your curve geometries. Try it like in the following live example:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
render();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.set(0, 0.5, 2);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const curve1 = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
    new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(2, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(2, 1, 0)
  );

  const geometry1 = createGeometry(curve1.getPoints(32));

  const curve2 = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
    new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-2, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-2, 1, 0)
  );

  const geometry2 = createGeometry(curve2.getPoints(32));

  const geometry = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries([geometry1, geometry2]);

  const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();

  mesh = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function createGeometry(points) {

  const vertices = [];
  const segments = points.length - 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++) {

    const point1 = points[i];
    const point2 = points[i + 1];

    vertices.push(point1.x, point1.y, point1.z);
    vertices.push(point2.x, point2.y, point2.z);

  }

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));

  return geometry;

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.145/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.145/examples/js/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js"></script>
```